# WCF connection closed, not a serialise exception

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I'm currently working on this issue for a week now and can't figure out what exactly is going on here.

I have a long running service operation (called CalculatePyramidValues) which is a void and with a nullable long as parameter. This operation takes approximatly 15 to 20 minutes to execute.

In my development environment this goes well but when i execute it on the production server i get the following (dutch) exception:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

which is an ordinary TargetInvocationException with the following stacktrace:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    Server stack trace:
      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]:
      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
     at Ifunds.M3.WCF.IService.CalculatePyramidValues(Nullable`1 processId)
     at Ifunds.M3.WCF.Client.WCFServiceClient.CalculatePyramidValues(Nullable`1 processId)
     at Ifunds.M3.WCF.Client.WCFServiceClient.<CalculatePyramidValuesAsync>b__3b(Boolean updateStatus, Future`1 f)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InvokeFuture(Object futureAsObj)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Ifunds.M3.WCF.Client.Future`1.<OnCompleted>b__6(Exception ex)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
     at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
     at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
     at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

I know most of the time this is because it can't serialize something. I used the WCFTraceViewer and can't find anything suspicious. It doesn't throw an exception at all on the serverside.

Then i thougt, it has to be a timeout somewhere, I checked all of them (Open, Close, Send and Receive) and they are all way bigger than the execution time (Open and Close are both a minute while Send and Receive are both six hours). The execution time of this method is approximately 15-20 minutes.

The weird thing is that when i tried to reproduce this from my home computer, i couldn't reproduce this, so i let some other colleagues test it from their home computers and *some* of them also get the exception, while others don't.

Then i tried using fiddler to see what's happening and than the weirdest thing happened: The problem didn't occure at all. So it looks like fiddler does something that prevents the connection from being closed.

I tried to see what the differences were between executing with and without fiddler (Used wireshark to do this) but couldn't find any real differences. But that having said, i'm not that experienced with debugging on such a level.

I'm really hoping that somebody here is able to help me out here cause i'm out of options.

Comment: have you tried this http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/wcf-underlying-connection-was

Comment: As an aside if it is taking 15 - 20 mins to run you might want to make this async or a callback.

Comment: @Dhaval-Patel: We've already increased the sizes cause we also have service operations which are returning a huge amount of results, however, this one doesn't return anything so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Belogix: We've tought about that, however, we want to know when the operation is finished and for now, we don't have a way to do a callback (were stuck on a half-duplex http binding)

Comment: @LangeJan - You could do one-way call to WCF (it is `void` after all) and then have a light-weight poll method that will check when the long running method has finished. This would probably be the easiest way to implement "Long polling" without doing much work.

Comment: @Belogix: Altough it's a good idea, it's not reachable for us to implement this at the moment (due to the way we create these operations).